# Why Doesn't VBA replace function work with CRLF in Word and Excel

Tags: vba, replace, chr

I could have sworn I have stripped CRLF in the past but not sure why the following isn't working:

```
myString = "ABC" & vbCrLf & "DEF"
str1 = Replace(myString, vbLf, "")
str2 = Replace(str1, vbCrLf, "")
str3 = Replace(str2, vbNewLine, "") 
MsgBox str3
```

The code above doesn't work the result is:

```
ABC
DEF
```

---

```
myString = "ABC" & vbCrLf & "DEF"
str1 = Replace(myString, Chr(13), "")
str2 = Replace(str1, Chr(10), "")
MsgBox str2
```

The code above does work the result is:

```
ABCDEF
```

Solution: Thanks @ Mat for the answer (The problem on the first code was the order I was trying to remove the items)
VbCrLf & VbNewLine is the same and trying to remove the combo vbCr+VbLf after removing VbLf won't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The premise is flawed:

```
myString = "ABC" & vbCrLf & "DEF"
```

The string is made of "ABC", `vbCrLf`, and "DEF".

`vbCrLf` is `vbCr` and `vbLf`, which on any Windows box is `vbNewLine`.

When you do:

```
str1 = Replace(myString, vbLf, "")
```

You replace `vbLf` ***and leave the `vbCr` character in place***.

```
str2 = Replace(str1, vbCrLf, "")
```

Then you replace `vbCrLf` *but `vbLf` is already gone so `vbCrLf` isn't in the string*.

```
str3 = Replace(str2, vbNewLine, "")
```

Then you replace `vbNewLine` which is basically doing the exact same thing as the previous instruction, and the result is a string that's been stripped of `vbLf` **but still contains `vbCr`**.

This code works as expected:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim foo As String
    foo = "foo" & vbCrLf & "bar"
    Debug.Print foo
    foo = Replace(foo, vbNewLine, vbNullString)
    Debug.Print foo
End Sub
```

As does this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim foo As String
    foo = "foo" & vbNewLine & "bar"
    Debug.Print foo
    foo = Replace(foo, vbNewLine, vbNullString)
    Debug.Print foo
End Sub
```

Or this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim foo As String
    foo = "foo" & vbNewLine & "bar"
    Debug.Print foo
    foo = Replace(foo, vbCrLf, vbNullString)
    Debug.Print foo
End Sub
```

Or even this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim foo As String
    foo = "foo" & vbNewLine & "bar"
    Debug.Print foo
    foo = Replace(foo, vbCr, vbNullString)
    foo = Replace(foo, vbLf, vbNullString)
    Debug.Print foo
End Sub
```

---

Your second snippet works as intended, because you *do* remove both `vbCr` (`Chr(13)`) and `vbLf` (`Chr(10)`) characters. Simple as that.

Comment: Wow it was the order. Thanks very much for that clarification.  I never thought about it that way (this time) but I did use it in the past and must have thought about it more logically.  Thanks again

Comment: @MickeyD well... it *wasn't* the order. Your code removed `vbLf` and left `vbCr` in the string; every further replacement involving `vbCrLf` and `vbNewLine` was no-op. Rule of thumb if you're on Windows you don't need to care about `vbCr`, `vbLf` or `vbCrLf` - just use `vbNewLine` and everything will just work. If the first replacement you did was for `vbNewLine`, then any further `vbCrLf` or `vbCr` or `vbLf` replacement would be no-op as well. Also note `vbNullString` instead of `""`; the latter is allocated a whole 2 bytes, the former is a 0-byte null pointer.

Comment: @Matt thanks but I have to politely clearly explain the way I meant to explain it.  Think about it this way. If I would have used
str2 = Replace(myString, vbCrLf, "") first then it would have worked. I just tried it by itself and it worked fine. I didn't need to remove them individually: VbCr or VbLf . There would be no chr(10) or chr(13) to remove in any following steps so if I would try to remove them afterwords, my result will still be correct but it would have wasted 2 extra lines of code. Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: Correct indeed - I was just saying that *just* reordering the instructions would have left you with one working instruction and then a bunch of redundant no-op ones ;-)

Comment: thanks again for clarifying it. 50/1 odds I will do the same mistake 10 years from now and have something to look back at.